# Use multiple logins in the same docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory

I am trying to pull images from the same Artifactory repo using 2 different access tokens. This is because one image is available to one user, and another one is accessible by another user.

I tried using docker login, but I can login only once to a repo. Is there a way to specify in the docker-compose.yml file a user and token that Compose should use in order to pull the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docker-compose file specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) does not support providing credentials per service / image.

But putting this technicality aside, the described use case clearly indicates there is a user who needs access to both images...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't thought of changing the user's permissions to the image... ‍♂️